# Getting image of form without border using "Form.DrawToBitmap"

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I am trying to use Form.DrawToBitmap to get an image of the current form. It works fine but shows the window border. How could I get it to create a bitmap of the form without the border.

Note: I'm aware that changing the form border style to "None" would work but switching the form border style twice (to "None" and back) at runtime is not really something I want every end-user to be seeing every time this function procs.

Answer (score 1):

First use `DrawToBitmap` method and then crop the image by cloning it and give your desire rectangle somthing like:

```
    private Bitmap ConvertToImage()
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
        {
            this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.Bounds);
            return bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(DESIRE_X, DESIRE_Y, DESIRE_WIDTH, DESIRE_HEIGHT), bitmap.PixelFormat);
        }
    }
```